# Merge an array of arrays in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, arrays, concatenation

I have the following controller which was a result of another OP on Stack Overflow.

```
var getData = function() {
        var swindon = $http.get('(url)/swi/10?expand=true'),
            paddington = $http.get('(url)/pad/10?expand=true'),
            reading = $http.get('(url)/rdg/10?expand=true');
        $q.all([swindon,paddington,reading]).then(function(arrayOfResults) {
            $scope.listOfServices = arrayOfResults;
            console.log($scope.listOfServices);
        });
    };

  getData();
```

Which results in something like this

[image]

What I would like to do NOW is CONCAT these three arrays into ONE array. The arrays are absolutly identical in structure with the records being stored in the trainServices array

I have tried something along the lines of

```
$scope.listOfServices = $scope.listOfServices.data.concat(data);
```

which comes back as undefined

I can use the arrays in a nested NG-REPEAT, but I need to filter out duplicates from the three arrays, so I need them as one. The data is from a live feed so I cannot do the query before the data gets to the app.

This is how I call the arrays at the moment

```
<tbody ng-repeat="item in listOfServices">
      <tr ng-repeat="service in item.data.trainServices | customDelayFilter">
```

I have also included an ONLINE JSON representation of JSON.stringify($scope.listOfServices)

[image]

Not sure why the top level says JSON.. thats not actually a string in the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try:

```
$scope.listOfServices = [].concat(...arrayOfResults.map(item => item.data.trainServices));
```

it should give you *concated* array of trainServices' objects

```
arrayOfResults.map(item => item.data.trainServices)
```

this code in our case returns an array of three trainServices arrays, using `Array.prototype.map` function

```
...arrayOfResults.map(item => item.data.trainServices)
```

this code uses [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) operator, which enables us to pass our array of arrays to `Array.prototype.concat` function, which merges those arrays of objects

Comment: 'Array.concat is not a function'.. and what is the ...arrayOfResults? why three dots?

Comment: I updated my answer, and replaced Array.concat (native Array object's method, which is equal to Array.prototype.concat(), [].concat()), ([]).concat()) with [].array. If it still does not work for you, I will try to create a plunker for you

Comment: I just want to say that you are like, my most favourite person this year. Works PERFECTLY and is actually a vast improvement on what I had. I now have a beautiful list of all merged services. Fantastic!

Comment: There is only ONE issue (which is breaking one of my custom filters) the first object in the new array is ALWAYS empty. Is this due to the [] at the beginning which we are adding to? should I put some blank data in here maybe.. hmm..

Comment: No tried that.. then I get an object with my dummy array, NULL, the rest of the objects. Maybe one of the feeds is dead

Comment: Yup, one of the feeds was dead.. i need to sort THAT out.. maybe I will need to iterate over each array..

Comment: you can always add a filter: $scope.listOfServices = ([].concat(...arrayOfResults.map(item => item.data.trainServices))).filter(item => item);

Comment: I have two date fields.. ETD and STD in the format "2017-01-16T14:14:00", basically if ETD - STD > 5 then the record is allowed.. hence the custom filter. Probably need to raise a new  request for this one

Comment: Wait.. I am overthinking it.. i just use that filter to make sure there is something actually THERE. A constant is trainid.. without that there is no record

Comment: I just added item=>item at the end.. and that stops the error

Comment: yes, it filters out null, empty string, 0 and undefined values

Comment: I will end this additional services discussion now, but if possible, I like you EVEN MORE! I gained some awesome tools here and cant thank you enough.