# PHPStorm plugin query

Tags: angularjs, plugins, phpstorm-2016.1

I have the following line of code in an AngularJS project

```
$scope.listOfServices = ([].concat(...arrayOfResults.map(item =>item.data.trainServices))).filter(item => item);
```

This code works perfectly, however PHPStorm is kicking off saying its full of errors and it expects a new line and so on. This means on the rare occasion I reformat my code as I had a late night coding and got messy, PHPStorm moves the code around and breaks it.

I have AngularJS plugins, JavaScript plugins etc. What plugin can I install to STOP PHPStorm thinking the above line is broken.

Comment: `$scope.listOfServices = ([].concat(...arrayOfResults.map(item =>item.data.trainServices))).filter(item => item);` this is full of syntax errors. PHPStorm is right.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.. though it doesn't throw any errors on execution. Does exactly what is required. Based on a previous SO question where I wanted to merge loads of remote data calls into a single array

Comment: If I past your line of code into my PHPStorm it shows a lot of syntax errors. The `...` isn't a JavaScript command at all. The `map` function of JavaScript is like `arr.map(callback[, thisArg])`, Yours is `arrayOfResults.map(item =>item.data.trainServices)`. If this code works, I'll eat my grandma and she is very tough... :P

Comment: Start munching, this code is already in production and working perfectly to merge data from 80 separate feeds into one array. See answer where it was provided http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675244/merge-an-array-of-arrays-in-angularjs/

Comment: Holy crap, you are right. http://jsfiddle.net/bk8h3efa/1/ mhm in that way -1 grandma. `...` = rest operator, wow. Never saw that before. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: You may going to create a bug issue over here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI PHPStorm supports JavaScript highlight / syntax autfill so there should be no need for a third party plugin.

Comment: Thanks, if you put that as your answer, I can accept it.

Comment: Cheers m8, thanks for shown me a realy unkown operator!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right!!!

`myFunction(...iterableObj);` = [Spread-Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) - This should be supported by PHPStorm JavaScript syntax validator.

You may going to create a bug issue over here: [youtrack.jetbrains.com](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI). PHPStorm supports JavaScript highlight / syntax autfill / validations so there should be no need for a third party plugin.

Comment: Nice gonna watch that one :)